# Why can't python-colormath convert sRGB to Adobe RGB?

Tags: python, color-space

This seems like such a simple problem, exactly what `colormath` was designed for. But calling `convert_color` appears to return the same object that was passed in. According to [the documentation](http://python-colormath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conversions.html) a failed conversion should raise a `UndefinedConversionError`, not return an object.

```
>>> from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, AdobeRGBColor
>>> from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
>>> srgb = sRGBColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
>>> srgb
sRGBColor(rgb_r=0.0,rgb_g=1.0,rgb_b=0.0)
>>> argb = convert_color(srgb, AdobeRGBColor)
>>> argb
sRGBColor(rgb_r=0.0,rgb_g=1.0,rgb_b=0.0)
>>> argb is srgb
True
```

It does work to convert to `Lab` so I'm unsure what the problem could be.

```
>>> from colormath.color_objects import LabColor
>>> convert_color(srgb, LabColor)
LabColor(lab_l=87.73500278716472,lab_a=-86.1829494051608,lab_b=83.1795364492565)
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `conversion` variable in the [convert_color](https://github.com/gtaylor/python-colormath/blob/fa1aa638c421e6a8ca23fb3bcc48d43da523fff8/colormath/color_conversions.py#L939) definition using your example is an empty list, meaning that there is no conversion to perform, thus the definition is not failing and returns `new_color` which is initialised with your original *sRGB* colour. I'm not exactly sure why this is the case though.

Alternatively, I'm the maintainer of another Python [Colour Science](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) API that would work for your case, it is however probably more involved than `colormath` because not abstracting conversions:

```py
import colour

colour.RGB_to_RGB(
  (0, 1, 0), 
  colour.models.sRGB_COLOURSPACE, 
  colour.models.ADOBE_RGB_1998_COLOURSPACE)


# array([ 0.28488056,  1.        ,  0.04116936])
```